# Custom Schema Type in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to MongoDB, working on a project which is a professional network where I have to differentiate between `ObjectId`s of the same field in a Schema. Let's say I have

**Schema:**

```
TestSchema = new Schema({
    Invitation: {
        from: [
            type: schema.types.objectid,
            ref: 'User'
        ]
    }
});
```

`Invitation` can be of different types like Event invitation, invitation to a connection request, like LinkedIn, or invitation to a live conference or discussion. Now if I follow the above schema then `ObjectId`s of different types of invitations will be stored in same field `from` which would not be *generic* and difficult to fetch or differentiate which `ObjectId` belongs to which invitation type. Like just in case if I store them in a single array `[]`, I want to make each `ObjectId` inside that array easy to differentiate. For example:-

```
{
    Invitation: {
        from: [Objectid(A), Objectid(B), Objectid(C)]
    }
}
```

Let's say `A` belongs to Event invitation, and `B` & `C` belongs to different type of invitation. The above example is the logic I came up with. I also considered using sub array fields, or sub-documents for different invitation types but then I think there should be a *generic* way of doing that. I've spent considerable amount of time on google looking for the logic with **custom objectid** concept and not sure if that concept is useful for what I want here.

Comment: You don't need to distinguish between `ObjectIds`, rather you could have a field named `type` in the `User` collection, which marks the type of invitation. Once mongoose `populates` the reference, you could query the `type` field.

Comment: ok correct me if i am wrong, this is what you are trying to say: Schema(){
type:{
       //this should be empty object or do i have to give reference of user 
}
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much i understand your question, you should create User or Event type Schema like:

```
EventType = new Schema(){
type: String,
eventID: {
type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
ref: 'User'}
}
```

and easily access this on server side by creating EventType object

```
var eventType = new EventType();
eventType.type = 'event'
eventType.eventID = //ObjectId of event doc
```

Answer (score 0):

@BatScream suggests that you should put a "type" field in your `User` schema.

```
var User = new Schema({
    username: ...
    ...

    type: String        

});
```

So that you'd be able to differentiate between (and *store*) the type in your referenced `User` schema.

```
TestSchema.findById(xxx, function(err, test){
    test.invitation.from[0].type == user.type
});
```

---

But if I understand your use-case properly, I think your `type` of the invitation is actually a *relationship* between your `User` and `Invitation` (which is stored inside `TestSchema` (whatever that is)). If that's so, you probably wouldn't want to store `type` inside the `User`. Perhaps store it in the `Invitation` itself...

```
TestSchema = new Schema({
    Invitation: {
        from: [{
            type: String,
            user: {
                type: schema.types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

So that you'd be able to differentiate between (and *store*) the type in your **`TestSchema`**

```
TestSchema.findById(xxx, function(err, test){
    test.invitation.from[0].type == 'event' ??
    test.invitation.from[0].user == 'user' ...
});
```

---

Additionally, and probably even off-topic, but [Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/) is great for handling such data. In that the "*relation*" between the User -and-> Invitation would *itself be an entity* in which you could store the type.